# Problemas de nombre del " id" o No reconoce el "id"

Tags: javascript, html, css, webforms

Hola quiero migrar una plantilla a *WebForm* , por lo tanto intente copiar el código html con sus librerías (css,js) y al  ejecutar la pagina aspx , me sale el error de nombre de los ID de mis etiquetas.

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo todo el contenido del head : 

    Translogic – Just another WordPress site
    
    
    
    
    http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/' />
    http://fonts.googleapis.com/' />
    http://s.w.org/' />

```
<style type="text/css">

    img.wp-smiley,
    img.emoji {
        display: inline !important;
        border: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        height: 1em !important;
        width: 1em !important;
        margin: 0 .07em !important;
        vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
        background: none !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css' href='wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles1c9b.css?ver=4.6.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sb_instagram_styles-css' href='wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/css/sb-instagram.minb493.css?ver=1.4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sb_instagram_icons-css' href='../maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min4698.css?ver=4.6.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-plugin-settings-css' href='wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/css/settings4ee1.css?ver=5.3.1.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='rs-plugin-settings-inline-css' type='text/css'>

    #rs-demo-id {
    }
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='trx_addons-icons-css' href='wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/css/font-icons/css/trx_addons_icons-embedded4f4a.css?ver=4.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='swiperslider-css' href='wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/js/swiper/swiper.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='magnific-popup-css' href='wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/js/magnific/magnific-popup.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='trx_addons-css' href='wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/css/trx_addons.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='trx_addons-animation-css' href='wp-content/plugins/trx_addons/css/trx_addons.animation4f4a.css?ver=4.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='js_composer_front-css' href='wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min972f.css?ver=5.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='translogic-font-google_fonts-css' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%7CMontserrat%3A400%2C700%7CLora%3A400%2C400i%2C700%2C700i&amp;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&amp;ver=4.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='translogic-fontello-css' href='wp-content/themes/translogic/css/fontello/css/fontello-embedded4f4a.css?ver=4.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='translogic-main-css' href='wp-content/themes/translogic/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='translogic-colors-css' href='wp-content/themes/translogic/css/__colors4f4a.css?ver=4.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='translogic-styles-css' href='wp-content/themes/translogic/css/__styles4f4a.css?ver=4.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mediaelement-css' href='wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.min51cd.css?ver=2.22.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-mediaelement-css' href='wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.min4f4a.css?ver=4.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='translogic-responsive-css' href='wp-content/themes/translogic/css/responsive4f4a.css?ver=4.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/jquery/jqueryb8ff.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min4ee1.js?ver=5.3.1.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min4ee1.js?ver=5.3.1.5'></script>

<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='wp-json/index.html' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="xmlrpc0db0.html?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.7.11" />
<link rel="canonical" href="index.html" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='index.html' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed06e9.json?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftranslogic.themerex.net%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed4c38?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftranslogic.themerex.net%2F&amp;format=xml" />
<meta name="generator" content="Powered by Visual Composer - drag and drop page builder for WordPress." />
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://translogic.themerex.net/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/vc_lte_ie9.min.css" media="screen"><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">

    body.custom-background {
        background-color: #edece8;
    }
</style>
<meta name="generator" content="Powered by Slider Revolution 5.3.1.5 - responsive, Mobile-Friendly Slider Plugin for WordPress with comfortable drag and drop interface." />
<link rel="icon" href="wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-Favi-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-Favi-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-Favi-180x180.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://translogic.themerex.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-Favi-270x270.png" />
<style type="text/css" data-type="vc_shortcodes-custom-css">
    .vc_custom_1478534944527 {
        background-color: #f7f6f2 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1478525086569 {
        background-image: url(wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bg-2f3e1.jpg?id=499) !important;
        background-position: 0 0 !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1479506271979 {
        background-image: url(http://translogic.themerex.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/counter.jpg?id=728) !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1479506567738 {
        background-color: #1f2e39 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1478533897962 {
        background-color: #f7f6f2 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480282486297 {
        background-image: url(http://translogic.themerex.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bg_image.jpg?id=992) !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1478532881550 {
        background-color: #faf9f5 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1478526798504 {
        background-color: #f7f6f2 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1479745581337 {
        background-color: #fefefe !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1479809364643 {
        background-color: #293842 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480334416208 {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) !important;
        *background-color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480289643519 {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480281211046 {
        padding: 10px !important;
        background-color: #ffffff !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480281219262 {
        padding: 10px !important;
        background-color: #f7f6f2 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480281230540 {
        padding: 10px !important;
        background-color: #1f2d37 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480281239204 {
        padding: 10px !important;
        background-color: #db5045 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480279416544 {
        margin-bottom: 0.8em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1479685995166 {
        margin-bottom: 0.75em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1485353303921 {
        margin-right: 10% !important;
        margin-left: 10% !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1479686195378 {
        margin-bottom: 0.8em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480279355953 {
        margin-bottom: 0.75em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1485353314681 {
        margin-right: 10% !important;
        margin-left: 10% !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480279444602 {
        margin-bottom: 0.8em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480279365886 {
        margin-bottom: 0.75em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1485353323002 {
        margin-right: 10% !important;
        margin-left: 10% !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480279474816 {
        margin-bottom: 0.8em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1480279376271 {
        margin-bottom: 0.75em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1485353331842 {
        margin-right: 10% !important;
        margin-left: 10% !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1479744554018 {
        margin-top: -16.5em !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1479807212777 {
        background-color: #f7f6f2 !important;
    }

    .vc_custom_1483965158633 {
        margin-bottom: 0.5em !important;
    }
</style>
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
    .wpb_animate_when_almost_visible {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style></noscript>
```

Comment: podrias porfavor colocar todo el codigo

Comment: excelente estimado en unos minutos lo hago.

Comment: en asp.net las etiquetas html se escriben de otra manera, te recomiendo familiarizarte con asp.net  ,luego con ese conocimiento podras pasar tu plantilla html estatica de la manera correcta.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario Elon , podrías compartirme un link que pueda ayudarme , te lo agradecería de corazón .

Comment: Comparte tu codigo .aspx del original y del que copiaste, probablemente sea las referencias que van al inicio de la hoja .aspx o .aspx.cs

Comment: listo estimado ahora comparto los dos codigos el html y el de aspx

Comment: estimado el codigo de las dos paginas son demasiadas largas y por lo tanto no veo posible de su utilidad . crees que me puedas ayudar con algun link por favor .